# R plot labels formatting

Tags: r, plot

I just want to have `# ###` numbers in the axes on my plot. For example, not `3500000`, `3000000`, but `3 500 000` and `3 000 000`. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `prettyNum` function with `big.mark = " "` and use them as labels in the `axis` call. To remove the default axis labels, you can use `xaxt="n"` for the x-axis, `yaxt="n"` for the y-axis or `axes=FALSE` for both axes.

Example:

```
plot(rnorm(1e4),xaxt = "n")
axis(1,at = labs <- pretty(par()$usr[1:2]),labels = prettyNum(labs,big.mark = " "))
```